# Pandas DataFrame: How to extract the last two string type numbers from a column which doesn't always end with the two numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the possible confusion in the title, here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to merge my Parcels data frame with my Municipality Code look up table. The Parcels dataframe:

```
df1.head()

    PARID           OWNER1
0   B10 2 1 0131    WILSON ROBERT JR
1   B10 2 18B 0131  COMUNALE MICHAEL J & MARY ANN
2   B10 2 18D 0131  COMUNALE MICHAEL J & MARY ANN
3   B10 2 19F 0131  MONROE & JEFFERSON HOLDINGS LLC
4   B10 4 11 0131   NOEL JAMES H
```

The Municipality Code dataframe:

```
df_LU.head()
  PARID  Municipality
0   01  Allen Twp.
1   02  Bangor
2   03  Bath
3   04  Bethlehem
4   05  Bethlehem Twp.
```

The last two numbers in the first column of df1 ('31' in 'B10 2 1 0131') are the Municipality Code that I need to merge with the Municipality Code DataFrame. But in my 30,000 or so records, there are about 200 records end with letters as shown below:

```
        PARID           OWNER1  
299    D11 10 10 0131F  HOWARD THEODORE P & CLAUDIA S   
1007    F10 4 3 0134F   KNEEBONE JUDY ANN   
1011    F10 5 2 0134F   KNEEBONE JUDY ANN   
1114    F8 18 10 0626F  KNITTER WILBERT D JR & AMY J    
1115    F8 18 8 0626F   KNITTER DONALD
```

For these rows, the two numbers before the last letter are the Code that I need to extract out (like '31' in 'D11 10 10 0131F')

If I just use 
    pd.DataFrame(df1['PARID'].str[-2:])
This will give me:

```
PARID
...
299 1F
...
```

While what I need is:

```
PARID
...
299 31
...
```

My code of accomplishing this is pretty lengthy, which pretty much invloves:

1. Join all the rows that end with 2 numbers.
2. Find out the index of the rows that end with a letter in the 'PARID' field
3. Join the results from step 2 again with the Municipality look up dataframe.

The code is there:

```
#Do the extraction and merge for the rows that end with numbers
df_2015= df1[['PARID','OWNER1']]
df_2015['PARID'] = df_2015['PARID'].str[-2:]
df_15r =pd.merge(df_2015, df_LU, how = 'left', on = 'PARID')
df_15r

#The pivot result for rows generated from above.
Result15_First = df_15r.groupby('Municipality').count()
Result15_First.to_clipboard()

#Check the ID field for rows that end with letters
check15 = df_2015['PARID'].unique()
check15
C = pd.DataFrame({'ID':check15})
NC = C.dropna()
LNC = NC[NC['ID'].str.endswith('F')]
MNC = NC[NC['ID'].str.endswith('A')]
F = [LNC, MNC]
NNC = pd.concat(F, axis = 0)


s = NNC['ID'].tolist()
s

# Identify the records in s

df_p15 = df_2015.loc[df_2015['PARID'].isin(s)]
df_p15

# Separate out a dataframe with just the rows that end with a letter
df15= df1[['PARID','OWNER1']]
df15c = df15[df15.index.isin(df_p15.index)]
df15c

#This step is to create the look up field from the new data frame, the two numbers before the ending letter.
df15c['PARID1'] = df15c['PARID'].str[-3:-1]
df15c

#Then I will join the look up table
df_15t =df15c.merge(df_LU.set_index('PARID'), left_on = 'PARID1', right_index = True)

df_15b = df_15t.groupby('Municipality').count()
df_15b
```

It wasn't until I finished that I realized how lengthy my code was for a seemingly simple task. If there is a better way to achieve, which is a sure thing, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: In your 4th row, `0231A`, is `31` the `PARID` that has been contaminated with the `A` to the end? If this is the case, do you want to assume that for this row, the `PARID` is `31` and it needs to be appropriately joined with the other table? or do you want to completely EXCLUDE those rows where the last letter of `PARID` is an alphabet? Because I really don't understand what you're trying to do when you also want to join the table with the letters with a table with numbers?

Comment: The former one. I know for sure that 31, the two numbers before the letter, are the Municipality code. Somehow the local government just adds some letters to the end. Let me edit the question a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas string methods to extract the last two numbers

```
df1['PARID'].str.extract('.*(\d{2})', expand = False)
```

You get

```
0    31
1    31
2    13
3    13
4    31
```

Comment: @jezrael, its way too modest of you to say your knowledge of anything python related is poor :) I don't think $ at the end work in this case as that will enforce last 2 numbers and return a NaN if it find a character

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you care to explain what each syntax of `'.*(\d{2})'` does please? Or could you provide a link where I can learn about the string methods? This works for me and I just want to understand why it pick out the numbers even though they are strings. Thanks again.

Comment: And I couldn't see the other comment but I still want to learn. What do you mean by `$` at the end? How does the code look like?

Comment: Using regex here. You can read this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) to understand it better. We are trying to extract precisely two numbers (\d{2}) from the given string from the end of the entire string (.*)

Comment: $ sign is to enforce the end of the string but if we use $ sign here, it will ignore any string which has non-numeric data at the end

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Learning regex has been on my list. I will definitely peruse the documentation. I didn't even know what regex can do.

Comment: Its an extremely powerful tool. Looks gibberish till you don't know it, but very versatile once you get a hang of it. I came across a website with more regex examples, will send you the link. All the best:)

Comment: Also there might be a more efficient way to solve the rest of your problem, if you can post the expected output

Comment: Would deeply appreciate it as I'm having some difficulty reading the documentation due to a lack of sleep. I have the data at hand now. Allow me to edit my original post a little bit. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.replace` to remove all non-digits. After that, you should be able to use `.str[-2:]`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'PARID' : pd.Series(["M3N6V2 B7 13A 0131", "M3N6V2 B7 13B 
0131", "Y2 7 B13 0213", "Y2 7 B14 0213", "M5 N4 12 0231A"]),
                 'Owner' : pd.Series(["Tom", "Jerry", "Jack", "Chris", "Alex"])})


df1['PARID'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').str[-2:]
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you tell me what `(r'\D+', '')` does please? How can that select the items that I want?

Comment: `str.replace` is a function that takes two arguments the pattern and what to replace it with. The pattern is written with regex `\D+` selects everything that is not a digit. It then replaces everything that matches the pattern with "" (nothing). Take a look here: https://regex101.com/r/5nQWzR/ you can see that everything except digits gets selected by using \D+. If you like my solution please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['M3N6V2 B7 13A 0131','M3N6V2 B7 13B 0131','Y2 7 B13 0213', 'Y2 7 B14 0213', 'M5 N4 12 0231A' ], ['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Jack', 'Chris', 'Alex']])
df = df.T
df.columns = ['PARID', 'Owner']
print(df)
```

prints your left DataFrame

```
                PARID  Owner
0  M3N6V2 B7 13A 0131    Tom
1  M3N6V2 B7 13B 0131  Jerry
2       Y2 7 B13 0213   Jack
3       Y2 7 B14 0213  Chris
4      M5 N4 12 0231A   Alex
```

and now for your right DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
df['IDPART'] = None
for row in df.index:

    if df.at[row, 'PARID'][-1].isalpha():
        df.at[row, 'IDPART'] = df.at[row, 'PARID'][-3:-1]

    else:
        df.at[row, 'IDPART'] = df.at[row, 'PARID'][-2:]

df['IDPART']=df['IDPART'].apply(int) #Converting the column to be joined to an integer column
print(df)
```

gives:

```
                PARID  Owner  IDPART
0  M3N6V2 B7 13A 0131    Tom      31
1  M3N6V2 B7 13B 0131  Jerry      31
2       Y2 7 B13 0213   Jack      13
3       Y2 7 B14 0213  Chris      13
4      M5 N4 12 0231A   Alex      31
```

and then merge

```
merged = pd.merge(df, otherdf, how = 'left', left_on = 'IDPART', right_on = 'PARID', left_index=False, right_index=False)
print(merged)
```

gives:

```
              PARID_x  Owner  IDPART  PARID_y Municipality
0  M3N6V2 B7 13A 0131    Tom      31       31       Tatamy
1  M3N6V2 B7 13B 0131  Jerry      31       31       Tatamy
2       Y2 7 B13 0213   Jack      13       13    Allentown
3       Y2 7 B14 0213  Chris      13       13    Allentown
4      M5 N4 12 0231A   Alex      31       31       Tatamy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I was trying to find out how to set value for a specific part of a dataframe and your reply taught me `df.at` is just the way to do that. And I always wanted to use for loop in pandas dataframe. This is very informative. Just one small question: had you not done 'df['IDPART'].apply(int)', then it wouldn't be joined successfully? In other words, do the join fields of different df need to share the same type? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu: You are correct. Before joining you need to ensure that the columns are of the same data type. The thing is.. You can't say for sure how your DataFrame may end up (or just maybe I'm do not have a good understanding of how the datatypes are inferred), so I convert it to `int` just in case.

Comment: Good Point. Thanks. I will play with the code several more times to see how it goes. BTW, you commented that the other reply is smart. But I failed to see why it would work and pandas documentation on `str.replace()` isn't helping either. Could you tell what it does?

Comment: @BowenLiu: As per your problem statement, you narrowed down your problem to the following: If there is an alphabet in the end, take last 2 characters EXCLUDING the last character (which is a alphabet that you want to avoid). If the last character is not an alphabet, then simply return the last 2 characters of that row.. So what the user did was, replace all alphabets with empty space.. That now eliminated ALL alphabets, `str.replace(r'\D+', '')` is a regex expression to match a specific pattern which in this case I think, are digits. And that was smart way to approach the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to understand what the `(r'\D+', '')` part does. I know it must be replacing letters with `''` but I don't understand the expression of `'\D+'`. Where can I read and learn more about this? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu Google it!